# Wrap C++ class with nested types

Tags: cython

The [official documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#an-example-c-api) show an example where `Rectangle.h` only contains primitive types.

How would one wrap this class if

- `Rectangle.cpp` itself made use of `Blabla.h` which defined `BlaBla getBla(int x, BlaBla* ptr)`
- which would be a public method in `Rectangle.h`.

If I compile this with Cython, I get an `Unknown type` error for `Blabla`:

Q: How can I tell Cython where to find `BlaBla`? Do I need to write a custom wrapper for `BlaBla` as well?

An example:

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

#include "Blabla.h"   // This is the addition from the official example

namespace shapes {
    class Rectangle {
        public:
            int x0, y0, x1, y1;
            Rectangle();
            Rectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
            ~Rectangle();
            int getArea();
            void getSize(int* width, int* height);
            void move(int dx, int dy);
            // New method:
            BlaBla getBla(int x, BlaBla* ptr);
    };
}

#endif
```

Has accompanying `.pxd`

```
cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle() except +
        Rectangle(int, int, int, int) except +
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
        int getArea()
        void getSize(int* width, int* height)
        void move(int, int)
        // New:
        BlaBla getBla(int x, BlaBla* ptr);
```

Cython will complain about `BlaBla` being an unrecognized type

Comment: I think you need to create a short example to illustrate this. I'm pretty unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I added an example

Comment: Obviously,  BlaBla must be wrapped as well via cdef extern, so cython knows it

Comment: I see, and if `BlaBla` again defines `BlaBlaBla` I have to wrap that as well. For a large project where this just goes on and on I guess I should look into automatic wrapping tools.

Comment: However - if you don't actually need to use `getBla` then simply don't tell Cython about it and then you want have to tell Cython about `BlaBla`. Cython doesn't need to know about everything

Comment: I see, thank you, but I need `getBla`